# In Wso2 XACML get how to get custom attributes

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am authenticating a user using SAML where I have written a custom federated authenticator for which I'll be passing a `IP,ID,appname` and it'll call the rest web service to get the username, roles and extra attributes. So, after getting the response I am checking whether the username exists or not in userstore. If exists then authentication is successful for the user else I am throwing exception. But for executing the XACML policy, I need to use the request params again like `IP,ID,appname` to invoke web service, and based on this I need to get user attributes and XACML policy should consider these params to execute policy.

So, is there any way to achieve the above flow?

Below is the custom federated authenticator code.

```
package org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.customfed;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.FederatedApplicationAuthenticator;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.context.AuthenticationContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.model.AuthenticatedUser;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.customfed.internal.CustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ClaimMapping;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.User;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserRealm;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreException;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.Property;


public class CustomFedAuthenticator extends AbstractApplicationAuthenticator implements
                                                                             FederatedApplicationAuthenticator {

    private static String RE_CAPTCHA_USER_DOMAIN = "user-domain-recaptcha";
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CustomFedAuthenticator.class);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    

    
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void processAuthenticationResponse(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                 HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                                 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext)
            throws AuthenticationFailedException {
        
            if(httpServletRequest.getParameter(CustomFedAuthenticatorConstants.ID)==null || httpServletRequest.getParameter(CustomFedAuthenticatorConstants.ID).isEmpty()){
                LOGGER.info("Remote Service Call Authentication failed:::::::::::");
                throw new AuthenticationFailedException("ID is empty/null");
            }
            
            String userName = callDPPortalGetSession(httpServletRequest.getRemoteHost(),httpServletRequest.getParameter(CustomFedAuthenticatorConstants.APP_ID),httpServletRequest.getParameter(CustomFedAuthenticatorConstants.APPNAME));
            
            boolean isAuthenticated;
            UserStoreManager userStoreManager;
            IdentityUtil.threadLocalProperties.get().remove(RE_CAPTCHA_USER_DOMAIN);
            
            try {
                int tenantId = IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantIdOfUser(userName);
                LOGGER.info("Tenant Id is::"+ tenantId);
                UserRealm userRealm = CustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.getRealmService().getTenantUserRealm(tenantId);
                if (userRealm != null) {
                    userStoreManager = (UserStoreManager) userRealm.getUserStoreManager();
                    isAuthenticated = userStoreManager.isExistingUser(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername(userName));
                } else {
                    throw new AuthenticationFailedException("Cannot find the user realm for the given tenant: " +
                            tenantId, User.getUserFromUserName(userName));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOGGER.debug("CustomBasicAuthentication failed while trying to get the tenant ID of the user " + userName, e);
                }
                throw new AuthenticationFailedException(e.getMessage(), User.getUserFromUserName(userName), e);
            }
            
            if(!isAuthenticated) {
                LOGGER.info("Authentication Failed");
                throw new AuthenticationFailedException("Authentication Failed");
            }
            Map<ClaimMapping, String> claims = new HashMap<ClaimMapping, String>();
            String[] claimList= {"http://wso2.org/claims/identity/isLiteUser"};
            try {
                Map<String, String> userClaims = userStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                        (userName),claimList , null);
                LOGGER.info("userClaims::::"+userClaims);
                claims.put(ClaimMapping.build("http://wso2.org/claims/identity/isLiteUser", "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/isLiteUser", null, true), userClaims.get("http://wso2.org/claims/identity/isLiteUser");
            } catch (UserStoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUserObj = AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                    (userName));
            authenticatedUserObj.setAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifier(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                    (userName));
            authenticatedUserObj.setUserAttributes(claims);
            authenticatedUserObj.setUserName(MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername
                    (userName));
            authenticationContext.setSubject(authenticatedUserObj);
           
            
    }
    
    
    

    @Override
    protected void initiateAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                                 AuthenticationContext context)
            throws AuthenticationFailedException {
        super.initiateAuthenticationRequest(request, response, context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute(FrameworkConstants.REQ_ATTR_HANDLED, null);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContextIdentifier(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return "CustomFedAuth_Context_id";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomFedAuthenticator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {
        return "customfed";
    }
    
    private String callGetSession(String ipAddress,String appId,String ID) {
        //
        return null;
    }
    
    
    
    private String callGetUserAttributes(String ipAddress,String appId,String ID) {
        //
        return null;
    }
}
```